# What is the cadence in one’s voice called when speaking parenthetically?

Tags: single-word-requests

When speaking, is there a specific term for the inflection of one’s voice when adding a parenthetical comment such as,

> "I am, <sub>however,</sub>  unsure about this."

That drop in pitch when one says “however,” that is what I’m asking about.

Thank you

Comment: @KannE Thanks.  Hopefully someone will have an answer.

Comment: This Q is better asked on [linguistics.se]

Comment: They don't have an answer, either. There's no canonical term. I call it "flatting", because it usually is a little lower in tone than the normal intonation, and it's maintained without much tonal variation. This is the tonal register used for presupposed material.

Comment: @Kris How can I migrate it?

Comment: HeWhoShallNotBeNamed: Nothing to worry. If needed, the question will get closed here and migrated to the appropriate alternate site. In any case, as @JohnLawler noted, there's no canonical term for this.

Comment: @JohnLawler: That's a nice expression. In music, the ♭ symbol is derived from the Italian *bemolle*.

Comment: [sotto voce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sotto_voce) seems somewhat related, but generally (as KannE mentions) means lowering the volume, not pitch, of your voice.

Comment: A relevent term seems to be 'prosadic stress/intonation'   [Here](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Jnu8bxCXmvoC&oi=fnd&pg=PA261&dq=parenthetical+prosodic+stress&ots=an53tpQ02Q&sig=-SxOg3V2IdHCz1SLlVo5skcmd_Y#v=onepage&q=parenthetical%20prosodic%20stress&f=false) is a paper that discusses at length this sort of thing, but it doesn't seem to use a special term other than 'parenthetical prosadic intonation' -- which I doubt is really what you want!

Answer (score 1):

1) There is no single, agreed-upon term for the prosodic pattern of parenthetical constituents.
2) The most common and theory-neutral term is **comma intonation** (e.g. [Emonds 1976](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/007137165), [Culicover 1992](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199660230.001.0001/acprof-9780199660230-chapter-8), [Brinton 2002](http://npu.edu.ua/!e-book/book/djvu/A/iif_kgpm_The%20Structure%20of%20Modern%20English.pdf), [Huddleston & Pullum 2002](https://www.cambridge.org/ch/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/grammar-and-syntax/cambridge-grammar-english-language), etc.).
3) Some researchers, especially those working on the interaction between syntax and prosody, use the term **parenthetical dip** following work by Dutch linguist Carla Schelfhout (e.g. [Heringa 2012](http://www.let.rug.nl/heringa/apcopred.pdf)). I find this term quite adequate. 
4) Scholars who are interested mainly in the semantics of parentheticals tend to have a more fanciful terminology (e.g. the introduction of a **comma operator** or **comma feature** in [Potts 2007](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.532.75&rep=rep1&type=pdf), 
the rule **Align R** and so-called **comma phrases** and **lower order prosodic constituents** in [Selkirk 2005](https://people.umass.edu/selkirk/pdf/Comments%20on%20IntonPhrsing.pdf), etc.).
5) The actual phonetic realization of parentheticals is remarkably complex. Scientists working on the different phonetic attributes of parenthetical intonation (e.g. for artificial speech) tend to not have *one* comprehensive term for the phenomenon because they dissect it into its constituent parts, such as 'maximum and minimum pitch levels', 'high and low tones' (see [ToBI](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~agus/tobi/labelling_guide_v3.pdf)), 'length of pauses' or 'intonational phrasing' etc. (For a summary see for instance [Bodenbender 1999](https://dspace.library.uvic.ca/bitstream/handle/1828/2768/parantheticals_ChristelB_MA.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).)
6) Irrespective of the syntactic pattern involved, the following collocates are commonly used to describe intonation: **intonational contour**, **intonational pattern**, **prosodic cue** and **prosodic structure**.